# Joomla sql query usling NOT LIKE

Tags: php, mysql, joomla

I'm having a problem with an SQL query in Joomla, my code looks like this:

This gets the parameter from the module :

```
$variable = $params->get( 'variable', '' );
```

When I echo `$variable` I get result : 1

Portion  of query that works:

```
$db->setQuery("SELECT * FROM #__table AS t WHERE (t.id NOT LIKE '%1%'
AND t.published = 1
```

But when I try to use a variable it doesn't works.  How do I properly use a variable to the NOT LIKE, instead of the manually entered number ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: how are you passing variable to SQL statement?

Comment: This is a module... variable is one of module parameters..When i echo this paramtre ..i get the correct result

Comment: Have a look a the Joomla documentation for writing database queries rather that writing native SQL queries

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
$db->setQuery("SELECT * FROM #__table AS t WHERE (t.id NOT LIKE '%$variable%' 
AND t.published = 1 ");
```

Answer (score 0):

Do this

```
$db->setQuery("SELECT * FROM #__table AS t WHERE (t.id NOT LIKE '%{$variable}%' AND t.published = 1)");
```

should work.

granted this does not escape the value of `$variable` so be sure that you trust the source

Comment: first of i see i missed a ending parentheses on the query. secondly is the id field of the type int ? and if you echo/var_dump the query string, does it look proper

Comment: Yes the id is: int(11)

Comment: <? echo var_dump($variable);?>    ---->   string(1) "7"   7 is the id from variable

Comment: Can you check that the query string (what you send to $db->query()) become correct with the variable in it by printing it, also can you print out what you get from the function $db->getErrorMsg()

Answer (score 0):

I guess you found already your answer, but for the others:

```
$db->setQuery("SELECT * FROM #__table AS t WHERE (t.id NOT LIKE '. $db->quote('\'%.1.%\'')AND t.published = 1
```

check here : https://docs.joomla.org/Selecting_data_using_JDatabase